# How do I stop my mesh from scaling down when I pose it?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

When I pose my mesh , the mesh distorts and shrinks. I followed a tutorial online for weight painting and rigging, but it is in blender 2.79. Is this only a 2.8 problem or has it always been there? It does this to the head most prominently, but it has affected other areas too, like the fingers. However it hasn't affected the hand and arms, which I have weight painted the same way, by selecting the vertices in edit mode and assigning them to vertex groups that were made when I selected "parent with empty groups."

Here is what the model looks like when it is in resting position.

[image]

Heres what it looks like when I pose it.[image]

**Edit:** the problem seems to come from when weights are painted over the same vertices and are combine to equal more than 1, like when one weight from one bone is 1 and another weight from a different bone is 1 on top of the same vertices.

**Edit 2:** I've done some more testing and it seems like one bone's weight of 1 and another bone's weight of .25 on the same vertices seems to not cause shrinking.

Comment: if the correction in Weight Paint mode is not enough, use Vertex Groups assign, also, don't forget to remove from all groups if you see that a vertex group is influenced by a bone that is not supposed to affect it

Comment: deleting and resetting the vertex groups fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: making sure only one bone controls 100% of any vertex, worked thank you